# Выборка из БД если поле принимает одно из перечисленных значений

Tags: sql

Столкнулся с проблемой - в таблице есть, к примеру, поле `color`, в которое может быть записано число от 1 до 12, и есть поле `sect` - в него записывается произвольный численный `id`. Хочу сформировать запрос по типу:

```
 $tmp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gone WHERE color = '1' OR color = '2' OR color = '4' AND sect = '5'");
```

при том, чтобы выборка производилась, если `sect = 5`, а `color` равен либо 1 либо 2 либо 4. Можно ли такое?

Comment: все условия с `color`возьмите в скобки (`(color = 1 or color = 2...) AND ...`) или напишите `color IN (1, 2, 4) AND ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас не совсем верный запрос. У вас будет условие в виде "`color=1` или `color=2` или (`color=4` и одновременно `sect=5`)", т.е. `sect` будет действовать только на `color=4`. Для того, чтобы распространилось на все, надо взять в скобки.

Верный запрос будет как:

```
SELECT *
FROM gone
WHERE (color = 1 or color = 2 or color = 4) and sect = `5`
```

Comment: спасибо я подозревал что там что то подобное) но не смог правильно все оформить(